# How can I set a table row color in my repeater based on the values databound to that row in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater control:

```
 <table style="width: 100%">
     <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptOptions" OnItemDataBound="rptOptions_ItemDataBound">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="GridHeader">Account</td>    
                                        <td class="GridHeader">Margin</td>  
                                        <td class="GridHeader">Symbol</td>  
                                        <td class="GridHeader">Price</td> 
                                    </tr>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="GridRow"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOptionAccount"></asp:Label></td>
                                        <td class="GridRow"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOptionMargin"></asp:Label></td>
                                        <td class="GridRow"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOptionSymbol"></asp:Label></td>
                                        <td class="GridRow"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOptionPrice"></asp:Label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:Repeater>
                        </table>
```

And the following code-behind databound method:

```
protected void rptOptions_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                Option rowOption = (Option)e.Item.DataItem;

                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblOptionAccount")).Text = rowOption.Account;
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblOptionMargin")).Text = rowOption.Margin ? "Y" : "N";
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblOptionSymbol")).Text = rowOption.Symbol;
                       ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblOptionPrice")).Text = rowOption.Price.ToString("C", currencyFormat);

            }
        }
```

There are more columns in that grid, but I've slimmed it down just for the question.

Now, what I would like to do is change the tr's background color based on the price amount.  If it is within different levels, I would like to change the rows background color correspondingly.

Do I have to do this with javascript or is there some way I can get access to the table rows in the code-behind to set this color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make it to runat="Server"

```
<tr runat="server" ID="trHeader"></tr>
```

Then find that Table Row in by ID in your code behind in databound event, like what you are doing for other server side control and change color.

Answer (score 5):

another option:

```
<tr class="<%# GetClassForPrice( Container.DataItem ) %>">
```

and in code-behind

```
protected string GetClassForPrice( object data ) 
{
    var rowOption = (Option)data;
    if(rowOption.Price > 100) return "red";
    else return "green";
}
```

also... any reason you're not using data binding?  it would let you eliminate your ItemDataBound code-behind method.

```
<tr>
    <td class="GridRow"><%# Eval("Account") %></td>
    <td class="GridRow"><%# ((bool)Eval("Margin")) ? "Y" : "N" %></td>
    <td class="GridRow"><%# Eval("Symbol") %></td>
    <td class="GridRow"><%# Eval("Price", "{0:c}") %></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

**use this code inside repeter databound event.**

```
HtmlTableRow tr = (HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("trID"); 
tr.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can use is jQuery. Seeing you're using a repeater, that gives you full control over your output. Jquery can get into your table, look at the data and format it how you want it.

Look at: 
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/54

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Colorize

http://franca.exofire.net/js/demo_cross.html

Alternately you can use the Code behind in the repeater to set the CSS Class of the cells/rows/columns you need changed.

You'll need to make those controls server controls (require: ID="my_thing" runat="server"), create those controls (use the find control and bind them), then set the CSS class after you determine the value.

Answer (score 0):

Dave Thieben's answer works nicely, except that the css is missing.

If you add the following then the example will work:

```
table tr.red td { background-color:red; }
table tr.green td { background-color:green; }
```

Comment: Hi Bruce, in future you can actually edit other answers to correct things like missing CSS, or add a comment to their answer explaining the problem.